# module.exports = mongoose.model('customertype', CustomerTypeSchema) mongoose.model is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
//Customer Type Schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CustomerTypeSchema = new Schema({
  customertype: {
    type: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});
module.exports = CustomerType = mongoose.model(
  "customertype",
  CustomerTypeSchema
);
```

```js
//CustomerType Routes
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const CustomerType = require('../../../models/Settings/CustomerType');

//Create CustomerType
router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
  const newCustomerType = new CustomerType({
    customertype: req.body.customertype,
    description: req.body.description
  });
  newCustomerType.save().then(customertype => res.json(customertype));
});


//Read all the CustomerType data
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  CustomerType.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(customertype => res.json(customertype));
});

//Get Customer Type by id to edit
router.get("/edit/:id", (req, res) => {
  CustomerType.findById(req.params.id)
    .exec()
    .then(customertype => res.json(customertype))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ msg: "No Customer Type Found" }));
});

//Updating CustomerType using ids
router.post("/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  CustomerType.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)
    .then(customertype =>
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "Customer Type Updated Successfully" })
    )
    .catch(customertype =>
      res.json(400).json({ msg: "Error in Updating Customer Type" })
    );
});

//Deleting Customer Type using ids
router.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  CustomerType.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(customertype =>
      customertype
        .remove()
        .then(customertype =>
          res.status(200).json({ msg: "Customer Type Deleted Successfully" })
        )
    )
    .catch(customersubdepartment =>
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "Error in deleting Customer Type" })
    );
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hey Guys, I don't know what happen to my model suddenly it gave this error before it was working fine but now the error is still coming again and again. I have tried looking for answers out here in stackoverflow also but did not get any help.My mongoose version is "mongoose": "^5.0.12", Please someone guide me thru this.Thanks in advance.

Error that I get kinda looks like this
[image]

Comment: you could export your schema like   :-   export default mongoose.model('collection name to be', schema name);

Comment: OR try doing this:-  var prod = mongoose.model('product',productSchema);     :- 
    exports.model = prod;      ------ hope this works for you

Comment: No @Suresh Shetiar its still showing the same error

Comment: could you share a repo that could generate the same issue. And Have you tried in other system?

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const dataSchema = new schema({
    Name:{type:String},
    Question_No:{type:String},
    Option_1:{type:String},
    Option_2:{type:String},
    Option_3:{type:String},
    Option_4:{type:String},
    Priority:{type:String},
    Answer:{type:String}
})
module.exports = {data: mongoose.model('filedata', dataSchema)}
```

Comment: Hey guys I found out the solution to this error and it was that I have been nesting this particular Schema in so many models that was why it was showing the error. If I call this Schema in only two or three models it was working fine. Anyways thank you for your time and consideration to answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,If you have only one schema to export then use this

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('filedata', dataSchema)
```

or if you want to export multiple schema then use this

```
module.exports = {
  register: mongoose.model('register', registerSchema),
  product: mongoose.model('product', productSchema)
}
```